# In the Event Sourcing pattern, do you have two different classes for reading and writing events?

Tags: c++, domain-driven-design, event-sourcing

Should the **storing** of events in the event stream be implemented separately from the **reading** of events in the event stream?

For example, the following abstract base class provides a means of persisting events so that they can be replayed later.

```
class event_store_t {
public:
    virtual void store(const event_t& event) = 0;
    virtual ~event_store_t() {}
};
```

The interface for the concrete derived class used for testing is below:

```
class ostream_event_store_t : public event_store_t {
public:
    virtual void store(const event_t& event);
};
```

Now, when replaying the events at a later point in time, should there be a separate class to read the events. For example, the abstract base class appearing as:

```
class event_stream_t {
public:
    virtual boost::shared_ptr<event_t> read() = 0;
};
```

And the concrete derived class appearing as:

```
class istream_event_stream_t : public event_stream_t {
public:
    istream_event_stream_t(std::istream& input) : input_(input) {}
    virtual boost::shared_ptr<event_t> read() {
        // Read the event.
    }
};
```

Comment: Well there is `std::istream`, and there is `std::ostream`, but there's also the `std::iostream` for both reading and writing. Maybe you can use something similar?

Comment: That's true, I could use this. However, I'm asking from a design point of view. E.g., if the events were persisted in an RDBMS, would you have a `rdbms_event_store` object for storing events and an `rdbms_event_stream` object for reading events (possibly using the same connection), or would you have a single `rdbms_event_repository` (for lack of a better term) for both storing and reading events?

Comment: In the design, are the read and write required to be synchronised? If so, then yes, I would combine them, if not, the no. If the answer is sometimes, then I would look to something like the `tie` in `std` streams library where there would be read, write and a why to tie the two together when synchronisation is needed.

Answer (score 1):

> Should the storing of events in the event stream be implemented separately from the reading of events in the event stream?

Probably not?

The primary motivation to separate your load implementation from your store implementation is so that you can swap the implementations independently.

If that hasn't happened to you already, then you are front loading into your design the costs, on the assumption that separating the costs now is going to be more efficient than doing it later, keeping in mind that in this hypothetical "later" you are going to know more about the requirements for change than you do now.

That doesn't seem like a good bet.

That said, you may have noticed that the consumers that need read capability don't always need write capabilities, or vice versa.  So it might make sense to have a read *interface* that is separate from the write interface, with a single module that implements both.